# Suddenly failing to authenticate against SharePoint online after the weekend April 10-11

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication, azure

After the weekend (10-11 of April) I suddenly started failing to authenticate against multiple Sharepoint Online tenants with an app hosted in Azure using an AppId and Secret.

Through fiddling with the code i found out that raising NET framework (4.5 -> 4.6.1) and redeploying seemed to fix this for some tenants (and reverting back to 4.5 leading to error), but what i can´t figure out is why this is happening (and even some tenants seemed to not have any problems with the 4.5 versions).

I have not been able to find any news about changes other than there was a security update on the 14 of April for Sharepoint Online (so that does not align with when the problems started).

Has anyone else ran into this problem or has any idea whats happening?

The code is relying on "SharePointContext.cs" and "TokenHelper.cs" to authenticate.

Thanks

Comment: May be related to https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/6903.